# How to center a element in a flex with space-between where left element has different size

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a navbar with 3 items spaced with `space-between`, the one on the left is longer in width than the one on the left, this results in the item in the center being shifted to the right, how can i solve this?
[image: Proof of concept]

Answer (score -1):

To center the navbar instead of using `space-between` do this in your css file:

```
div#nav{
  text-align: center;
}
div#nav ul{
  display: inline-block;
}
```